# How to delete files selected by rules?

Tags: scripts, files, delete

I have a large list of `.mp4` files in one directory on a NAS(Network Attached Storage).

Some are listed as follows :

```
XXXXX_3800.mp4
```

and other like

```
XXXXX_8000.mp4
```

`XXXXX` is the same for both files.

I would like to automate delete the `XXXXX_8000.mp4` but ONLY if the file `XXXXX_3800.mp4` exists.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Is there a common pattern for `XXXXX` or every other pair has different pattern?

Comment: @heemayl Please, don't just improve the formatting, check the spelling and grammar as well.  BTW: a NAS is Network Attached Storage not a `linux command or output thereof`...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby: ....as you said so  ;)

Comment: Are the dupes in the same (sub) directory?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to a terminal by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `md bin`
2. Go to the dash
3. type `gedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Copy paste the following text into it:

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash

    #
    # This script deletes video files of 8000 bps if and only if the 3800 bps file exists 
    # as set in http://askubuntu.com/questions/581400/how-to-delete-files-selected-by-rules
    #

    # Copyright (c) Fabby 2015

    # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
    # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
    # You DID NOT receive a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program as the license is bigger than this program.
    # Therefore, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ for more details.

    for szFile in $(ls *3800.mp4)
    do
      if [ -f ${szFile:0:${#szFile}-8}'8000.mp4' ] ; then
        echo "deleting ${szFile:0:${#szFile}-8}8000.mp4..."
        rm -f ${szFile:0:${#szFile}-8}'8000.mp4'
      fi
    done
```

4. Save the file under `~/bin/del8000`
5. Go back to the terminal and type: `chmod +x ~/bin/del8000`
6. In the terminal type: `cd ~/Videos`
7. Type `del8000`

### Done!

Comment: I think it should be the other way around, if `XXXXX_3800.mp4` exists then delete `XXXXX_8000.mp4`, anyway same logic.

Comment: @heemayl: Why didn't you answer then?  You were editing the question!  Now I feel guilty for answering...  Were you making a script as well?

Comment: I was not quite sure about the OP's question to some extent and i edited it just one time before you overwritten it correctly. your solution is correct and i am just pointing that the match and delete should be the other way way around as per OP's question, nothing else. and you are a genius and i know that. ;)

Comment: You made me thing of something to make it faster!

Comment: '+1' for your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20818/discussion-between-fabby-and-heemayl).

Comment: I put it in the reverse order : #!/bin/bash

for szFile in $(ls *3800.mp4)
do
  if [ -f ${szFile:0:${#szFile}-8}'8000.mp4' ] ; then etc... I've save the del8000 file in /bin and chmod +x del8000 but when I try to run it, it says nothing and does not delete the *8000.mp4 file but there is actually a *3800.mp4 in the directory I've made the test.

Comment: Look at my revisions: https://askubuntu.com/posts/581417/revisions you can use the double if to do the reverse, but if would take longer... my source should be: faster and just work out of the box thus solving your issue straight away... :P ;-)

Comment: As you've never before accepted an answer on this site: If this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the abysmally small number at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)
Merci bien!  :P  ;-)

Comment: Sorry but as I said in my previous comment, this scripts DOES NOT delete the *8000.mp4 present in my test directory where I've put both *3800.mp4 and *8000.mp4 files.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I do the exact opposite: if the high-res exists, I delete the low res....  Adapted...  Testing... Tested...  This file deletes the High res file 8000 if the low-res 3800 exists

Comment: And @kasiya just improved it even further!  Thanks!

Comment: @Laurent06000: does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

#### In a single (flat) directory

If all files are in one and the same directory, the script below should do the job.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]; ids = ("_3800.mp4", "_8000.mp4")
checklist = [f[:-9] for f in os.listdir(dr) if f[-9:] in (ids)]
for f in [f for f in set(checklist) if checklist.count(f) != 1]:
    os.remove(dr+"/"+f+"_8000.mp4")
```

*How it works:*

- The script lists all files, ending with either `_3800.mp4` or `_8000.mp4`, stripped from their endings
- If the (stripped-) name occurs twice, both versions exist (since duplicate names are impossible in one and the same directory)
- Subsequently, the script removes the `_8000.mp4` - version from the duplicates

---

#### In a layered directory (search recursively)

A slightly different approach. It compares files *recursively* and (only) deletes the `_8000.mp4` - version if the `_3800.mp4` - version exists. 
I wasn't sure there was a need for a *recursive* search, but added it anyway.

*How it works:*

- First list the files to keep anyway
- Then remove possible "throw aways", *if* the version-to-keep exists.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

files_dir = sys.argv[1]; file_list = []
#---
keep = "_3800.mp4"; rm = "_8000.mp4"
#---
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(files_dir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(keep):
            file_list.append(name)
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(rm) and name.replace(rm, keep) in file_list:
            os.remove(root+"/"+name)
```

#### How to use

To use either one of these scripts:

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `clean_directory.py`
2. Run it, with the directory to clean up as an argument, by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/clean_directory.py </path/to/directory/to/clean>
   ```